# sprockets duplicate file naming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, sprockets

I have the following files, in my asset path:

```
javascripts/abc.js
templates/abc.js.mustache # this gets compiled to abc.js
```

naturally, they both would be requested as `assets/abc.js`.

Is there a fix?  If not, what part of the Sprockets source would need to be modified?

My thinking is along the lines that if the engine can remove the extension, it can well enough add a suffix.

Answer (score 1):

It may be too obvious, but isn't it better just rename files? I understand nature of your question, but it's hard to imagine ultimate requirements, which forces same filenames for those files. Hence this, you have `foobar.js` and `foobar.js.mustache`, which compiles to `foobar.js`. Why they have same names? They do same things? This is design flaw, if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and have not yet found a satisfying solution.  My sites have many complex full-stack plugins (aka engines), and they have lots of css, js, and image files.  Having to namespace, eg "styles.css" in each plugin kinda sucks.  When upgrading to Rails 3, I assumed the file resolver would put engines/plugins in /styles, but no, they all get combined into one virtual path.

My current temporary solution is to build a rake task that I run that checks for duplicate filenames.  I run it before committing code and on deployment.  Hackity!  If that helps, great, if not, perhaps someone out there has a more elegant solution...